# No response from MediaWiki API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, response, wikipedia-api

I've tried to get some content from Wikipedia as JSON:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles="+title+"&format=json", function(data) {
    doSomethingWith(data);
});
```

But I got nothing in response. If I paste to the browser's adress bar, something like

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=jQuery&format=json
```

I get the expected content. What's wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to trigger JSONP behavior with [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) by adding `&callback=?` on the querystring, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles="+title+"&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
    doSomethingWith(data);
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FPhcr/).

Without using JSONP you're hitting the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which is blocking the XmlHttpRequest from getting any data back.

Comment: Thank you so much for making such a simple fiddle. I've been hammering for hours and your simple thingy made me click. Thank you.

Comment: I was testing this for hours wondering why it didn't work even though http://jsonlint.com/ said that its a valid request. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. This is the only way I found to search Wikipedia: https://jsfiddle.net/tqeL3od2

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers point out, you are making a cross-domain request.

The one answer which works now and which they have both given is to use `JSONP` instead of `JSON`, but there is another answer called `CORS` [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

However, even though CORS is supported by MediaWiki, it is not yet enabled on Wikipedia due to subtleties between it and how Wikipedia's caching works.

There is an open bug report to get this working in Wikipedia: **[Enable $wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains for wikimedia sites](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20814)**.

Once this is resolved you will be able to make cross-domain AJAX requests to Wikipedia without needing JSONP from browsers which support CORS. The latest versions of all the major browsers now support CORS. For Internet Explorer that means version 10 which not many people are running. Version 9 has an alternative solution called [xdomainrequest](/questions/tagged/xdomainrequest) which didn't gain much popularity.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [`getJSONP`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if your getting data from another domain, it's part of the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".

**EDIT**

Actually what Nick said, slap `&callback=?` on the end of your query string to invoke `getJSONP`.

Comment: There is no `$.getJSONP()` :)

Answer (score 0):

One option to perform CORS request instead of JSONP is to explicitly include parameter `origin=*` in request url, for example:

```js
var title = "jQuery";

$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles="+title+"&format=json&origin=*", function(data) {
    console.log(data.query.pages);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```