# Server will not return AJAX GET request with CORS enabled

Tags: php, http, cors

I'm trying to enable external sources to make GET requests to my server. Right now I'm just testing it on my personal server with hosting through godaddy. Could that be an issue?

I have the following code on a page that I'm trying to make a request to

```
//page.php
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json")
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');  

include_once 'php_dom/simple_html_dom.php';
include_once 'phpQuery.php';


if(isset($_GET['item'])){
    echo json_encode(array("data" => $_GET['item']));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array("Error"=>"No item provided"));
}
```

I tried making a request like this (with my URL, obviously) and I'm not getting anything back.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/page.php?item=123&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Chrome developer shows a successful request but nothing is returned. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: For the purposes of testing, add an `else {echo json_encode(array("Error"=>"No item provided"));}`. Also, don't forget to set an appropriate Content-Type header... `header("Content-Type: application/json")` this should at least determine if the script is being called and it's a logic error or if you're not getting any response. Incidentally, does the network tab show an http 200 response with an empty body or ???

Comment: On what origin are you issuing the request? Is it from a local file or a different server?

Comment: I'm running server on localhost making a request to my "actual" server.

Comment: @Basic I updated my code above. Still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `callback=?` the response will be handled as JSONP. Try something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['item']) && isset($_GET['callback'])){
    echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode(array("data" => $_GET['item'])).');';
}
```

...or omit the callback-parameter.

Comment: I thought the callback=? was necessary to trigger JSONP as stated by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873636/no-response-from-mediawiki-api-using-jquery)

Comment: +1 Nice catch, I missed that. @user1443519 JSONP is required for x-domain requests which _don't_ have the `Access-Control-Allow` headers

Comment: So, that means I need it then? I'm new to this so I'm not sure if I'm interpreting it correctly. Obviously something is wrong considering it's not working.

Comment: @Basic, why is the OP's original code *not* working, since it does have the CORS headers?

Comment: @user1443519: you don't need JSONP because you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header to '*', but when you use the callback-parameter, the response is expected to be JSONP .

Comment: @Dr.Molle when I remove "callback=?" my requests are immediately canceled as shown in chrome developer

Comment: [If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

Comment: @Jonah does it have something to do with my server. I'm testing it out on my personal site which is hosted through godaddy. Are there some settings on there I have to change?

Comment: @user1443519, That's possible, but sorry, honestly I don't know

Comment: Last time I checked, even GoDaddy weren't that bad, although it's possible they're stripping the CORS headers... @user1443519 What do you see in a browser if you open that "page" url directly? This should help narrow down if it's a script problem or a same-origin issue

Comment: @user1443519: there is a semicolon missing after the first `header()`, the Access-Control-Headers will never be sent, all you will get is a empty response or a message related to the parse-error

Comment: @Dr.Molle I noticed that, just forgot to update my code above

Comment: I got it to work. I had to remove "callback=?" form the call. I'm not sure why the requests were being canceled at first.

Comment: JSONP and CORS are two solutions to the same problem and they're not really compatible. With CORS you return the same data in the same format as you would for same-domain requests but have to handle some HTTP headers specially. With JSONP you return the data modified to include function invocation where `callback=?` is part of jQuery's solution to use randomly generate such function names. With CORS you get pure data you can use in any way, with JSONP you get code in its own HTML script element which must be invoked to retrieve the data.