# Call external URL from AJAX in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to call a external URL (not in my development server) that returns JSON response. Doing some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613310/how-to-call-external-url-in-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873636/no-response-from-mediawiki-api-using-jquery) post and tried almost every, right now my code is this:

```
$("#query").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 32) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var noWhitespaceValue = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        var noWhitespaceCount = noWhitespaceValue.length;

        if (noWhitespaceCount % 3 === 0) {
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: "text=" + $(this).val(),
                url: "http://192.168.0.159:3000/products/search/all",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    request.abort();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But it's not working, so what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: JSONP would probably be the best.

Comment: You need to narrow your question WAAAYY down. Start with just running an Ajax call on load or something (just the .ajax) part and see if that fails or succeeds, edit your question once you do that, and we'll go from there

Comment: have you tried setting breakpoints in your script using browser developer tools such as Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome? If you are hitting the endpoint, try setting contentType: "application/json"

Comment: @TommyNicholas I did it already and it returns `200 OK 12ms` so call is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many times you bind the "keyup" ? Have you tried abort an previous request?

```
$("#query").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 32) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var noWhitespaceValue = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        var noWhitespaceCount = noWhitespaceValue.length;

        if (noWhitespaceCount % 3 === 0) {

         /* Aborting previous Requests */
         if(request) request.abort();

            var request = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: "text=" + $(this).val(),
                url: "http://192.168.0.159:3000/products/search/all",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    request.abort();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```