# Ajax function only succeeds with "alert"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**EDIT:** My question is *not* a duplicate of [No response from MediaWiki API using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873636/no-response-from-mediawiki-api-using-jquery). Because even though it's a cross-domain request, I'm properly triggering JSONP behavior because jquery is automatically sending a callback parameter under the hood. (As you can see from the link I posted `jQuery3100048749602337837095_1485851882249&_=1485851882253`

**EDIT2:** Solved by @AnandMArora. Solution:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="getUserInput(event)" style="display:none"/>
```

and function

```
getUserInput(evt) { evt.preventDefault();
```

But since it's a comment I can't mark it as the answer. If there's an explanation why this method works (what is the default behavior that is prevented etc.) I will select it as the answer.

I assume that the "alert" method is buying time for the AJAX function since it's asynchronous. But I have no idea WHY do I need to buy time here. It should only be executed  when `getUserInput()` calls `getWiki()` with the `Input` parameter. 
In fact, I looked at the network monitor and even if we remove `alert("")` the proper URL is called (assuming "batman" was submitted).

Request URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=batman&callback=jQuery3100048749602337837095_1485851882249&_=1485851882253

If I open this link manually, it works fine.
But there's no status code returned and console logs "Error!"

```
function getUserInput(){
  var Input = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  getWiki(Input); 
  alert(""); //If we remove this line the request fails
}

function generatePage(rawData) {
  console.log(rawData);
  var mainData = rawData.query.pages;
  $.each(mainData, function(value){
    console.log((mainData[value].title + " " + mainData[value].extract));
  });

}


function getWiki(Input){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=" + Input,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (rawData) {
      generatePage(rawData);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Error!")
    }
  });
}


$(document).ready(function(){


})
```

The html I'm using to submit is:

```
<form class="searchForm">
      <input type="text" name="searchRequest" id="searchBox" >
      <input type="submit" onclick="getUserInput()" style="display:none"/>
      </input>
    </form>
```

My questions would be:
1) Why is this happening?
2) How can this be fixed without turning `async` off or using `setTimeout()` on the ajax function?

Comment: you just add a callback error function in your ajax attribute

Comment: How is `getUserInput` invoked when you have set the `display` of the submit button to `none`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No response from MediaWiki API using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873636/no-response-from-mediawiki-api-using-jquery)

Comment: I set `display:none` in order to be able to submit requests with "Enter" without writing an event listener for an "enter" click.

Comment: have you tried using:_<input type="submit" onclick="getUserInput(**event**)" style="display:none"/>_ and function getUserInput(**evt**) { **evt.preventDefault();**

Comment: @AnandMArora It works! Thank you! You should have posted that as an answer. Could you explain why this works and why it didn't work before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **ajax**, and the input control type of "**submit**" has a default action of postback for the form in which it is placed. So jQuery and most javascript code use the `evt.preventDefault(); // evt is the object of event passed as a parameter for the click event function` this prevents the default action i.e. *submit the form*.

Please make the changes as :

`<input type="submit" onclick="getUserInput(event)" style="display:none"/>`

and

`function getUserInput(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); ...`

this will most probably be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap that console.log call inside a function:

```
function getWiki(Input){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=" + Input,
    datatype: "JSONP",
    type: "GET",
    success:
      function (rawData){
        generatePage(rawData);
      },
    error: 
      function(){
        console.log("Error!")
      }
  });
}
```

**Explanation:**

The ajax call expects functions definitions to be passed to its event handlers ('success'/'error' in this case).

You do this for the success handler.  For your error handler you are not pushing a function definition but a function that you are actually ***invoking*** (the console.log method).

Wrapping it in a function declaration (like what you did for the success event callback) allows you to define *what* happens on the callback *when* it is invoked rather than invoked it in-line.

Comment: That was simply a brain-fart. I fixed it now. But that wasn't the issue. The ajax call still fails if we remove `alert("")`.

Comment: Ahah...  This might be what you are looking for then:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873658/2902660

Answer (score 0):

1)You have to specify a callback function, don't put code directly (otherwise it will be executed) but put it in a function

> error: function(){console.log("Error!");}

2)In order to wait for the response, you have to specify that your request it synchronous

> Set `async` option to `false`

**If you need an asynchronous solution** please see the following snippets (using `done` method instead of `success` property):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="searchForm">
      <input type="text" name="searchRequest" id="searchBox" >
      <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:getUserInput()" />
      </input>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
  function getUserInput(){
    var Input = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
    getWiki(Input); 
    //alert(""); //If we remove this line the request fails
  }

function generatePage(rawData) {
  console.log(rawData);
  var mainData = rawData.query.pages;
  $.each(mainData, function(value){
    console.log((mainData[value].title + " " + mainData[value].extract));
      })

}


function getWiki(Input){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=search&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=" + Input,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    error: function(){console.log("Error!");}

  }).done(
      function (rawData) {
        generatePage(rawData);
      }
  );
}


$(document).ready(function(){


})
</script>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Comment: 1) Just a brain-fart. Fixed.

2) My original question was: "How can this be fixed **without turning async off** or using setTimeout() on the ajax function"?

I'd rather avoid the browser freezing while waiting for ajax to finish.